# Firing JQuery.Ajax events in Aspx page with multiple ID

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just started using JQuery.Ajax today and want to try using the same script for multiple 'a href' tags using name with same templates:

If i have a list of 'a href tags' example:

```
<a href='#modalbox' id="modalboxUpdateStaff$id1">Some Text</a>
<a href='#modalbox' id="modalboxUpdateStaff$id2">Some Text</a>
<a href='#modalbox' id="modalboxUpdateStaff$id3">Some Text</a>
```

And I want them to run the script:

```
    $('#modalboxUpdateStaff').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GenerateStaffPositionModalHtml",
            data: "{staffID: 1}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                $("#myCustomModalBody").text(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

Where I pass in the

> > value of $id

into my script's

> > data: "{staffID: id}"

How do I do that?

Comment: what do u mean **value of $id** ? do u mean elements id or the 1,2,3 after $id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make far more sense to use `class` and `data-*` attributes on your markup:

```
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="$id1">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="$id2">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="$id3">Some Text</a>
```

or if you just wanted to send the value 1, 2, 3, ...:

```
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="1">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="2">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" data-id="3">Some Text</a>
```

and then use a class selector and the `.data()` method to read the value of the id:

```
$('.modalboxUpdateStaff').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GenerateStaffPositionModalHtml",
        data: JSON.stringify({ staffID: id }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#myCustomModalBody").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Also notice that I have used `JSON.stringify` to ensure proper JSON encoding of the `data` parameter which is sent to the server.

Comment: In your code behind you could have the following PageMethod: `public static SomeResult GenerateStaffPositionModalHtml(int staffId) { ... }` and receive the `staffId` parameter as integer.

Answer (score 1):

First, your selector won't work, but you can match on the href. Then pass the id. As follows:

```
$('a[href="#modalbox"]').click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('modalboxUpdateStaff$id', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GenerateStaffPositionModalHtml",
        data: {staffID: id},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#myCustomModalBody").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Derek & Darin's excellent answers, I'd like to add one more way. Just to make things simpler, you could just store the `id` in the element's id and use class to reference all the tags :

```
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" id="1">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" id="2">Some Text</a>
<a href="#modalbox" class="modalboxUpdateStaff" id="3">Some Text</a>
```

So that, in your `ajax` call, you could just use,

```
$('.modalboxUpdateStaff').click(function () {
    //var id = $(this).data('id');
    var id= this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GenerateStaffPositionModalHtml",
        data: JSON.stringify({ staffID: id }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            $("#myCustomModalBody").text(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

I feel like this would be faster than using `data`, and saves more code, so here you go :)